# Entity is not deleted in a JUnit test with @Transactional

Tags: java, junit, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I use *@Transactional* annotation on my JUnit tests sometimes. I use @Transactional in JUnit for Lazy fetching collections.

Currently I have faced with an unknown behavior for me of *@Transactional* annotation.

In my database I have one *Car* entity. I am deleting this entity in my test. If I use *@Transactional* on my test, then this entity IS NOT deleted from a database.
Otherwise if I do not use @Transactional then the entity is deleted.
I see this after every test in my database.

I have standard entity and repository.
My entity:

```
@Entity 
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String model;

    //...constructors, getters and setters }
```

My repository:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer>{
    List<Car> findByModel(String mazda);
}
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RelationsTest {

    @Autowired
    CarRepository carRepository;

    @Test
    //@Transactional
    public void deleteCar() throws Exception {

        List<Car> cars = carRepository.findByModel("Mazda");
        assertThat(cars).hasSize(1);

        carRepository.deleteById(cars.get(0).getId());

    }
```

What is a reason that with *@Transactional* the entity is not deleted from a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications):

> If your test is @Transactional, it rolls back the transaction at the end of each test method by default.